# What is the difference between application console vs cluster console?

Tags: openshift, openshift-enterprise

What is the difference between application console vs cluster console  in openshift enterprise version. I am new to openshift and confused with terminologies. I feel that openshift is like linux kernel in our system(an analogy). On top of that are containers and to orchestrate we have kubernetes. However , the architecture of openshift is exact opposite. Please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

OpenShift is just one of the available [Kubernetes distributions](https://landscape.cncf.io/category=certified-kubernetes-distribution,certified-kubernetes-hosted,certified-kubernetes-installer&format=card-mode&grouping=category&selected=red-hat-open-shift), which adds enterprise-level services like authentication, authorization and multitenancy.

The web console provides two perspectives: Administrator and Developer. The Developer perspective provides workflows specific to developer use cases like create, deploy and monitor applications, while Administrator perspective is responsible for managing the cluster resources, users, and projects. Depending on the user's role, you will see a different set of views available in the main menu.